# Extending a bootstrap confidence interval to a larger population with a non-normal distribution

Tags: confidence-interval, bootstrap

Using Python/SciPy I calculated a bootstrapped CI on my sample.

```
import scipy 
import scikits.bootstrap as bootstrap
data.mean()
--> 17.269467
bootstrap.ci(data=data, statfunction=scipy.mean)
--> [ 16.59747002  17.9914076 ]
```

I produced numbers, but I want to understand what they actually mean. I think that what I calculated is not the statistic that I actually want.

My data is the number of pages in a document. Exciting stuff. A lot of documents have a single page only, but some can be several hundred pages. That is $$ Pr(X = 10) $$ is the probability that a given document will contain exactly 10 pages. I am trying to estimate the total number of pages in the population and the number of pages in an average document. The context is a large scale document scanning project, and the cost will be a function of both document count and page count. I'm interested in being able to give a range with confidence to establish a budget.

A few facts and assumptions

- the sample contains about 15% of the population
- the population will have around N ≈ 100,000, although exact size is unknown
- the distribution visually resembles $$ 1/x $$ but is not parametric

What confuses me is that the CI does not take into account the total size of the population. It seems to me that the population size should have an effect on the CI, but for some reason the population size is not a parameter. What does one do to extend this calculate to account for a population larger than the sample?